# How do I remove Skype from xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, xubuntu, skype

I know there are numerous posts on how to remove skype from ubuntu. However, I found none for 16.04 and more importantly no method worked for me.

I tried what I thought was most thorough:

```
apt-get purge skypeforlinux
apt-get autoremove --purge skypeforlinux
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq skypeforlinux
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
apt-get -f install
```

also, trying to manually remove package did not help:

```
rm -r ~/.config/skypeforlinux/
rm -v /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype*
```

I must admit that I dont remember how I installed it. Skype-repo is not listed in my sources-list. Also I cant find a .deb in my /Downloads which should be the case if I had installed it via .deb.
Sorry for this confusion.

The program just keeps showing up like a little microsoft daemon. I'd recommend anyone to use jitsi, mumble, ... instead.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you install Skype? Particularly did you install the deb or the snap version? Have you tried the GUI methods like Ubuntu Software or Synaptic? Please edit the question above and add more information.

Answer (score 9):

skype is perhaps installed as snap package
if so, here is how to uninstall it

```
snap remove skype
```

Answer (score 3):

1. find it:

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep skypeforlinux
   ```
2. Remove it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux
   ```